# in c file operation not to append

Tags: c, file, url-rewriting, append

I am trying to read from a file a matrix like that

1 2 3 5 6

4 5 3 5 6

After that ı change one of them and want to write it to same file.
But it appends to the end of file ; Is there a solution for this without using fseek() ı want to use file like every time ı use it it begins from the beginning.

```
in main(){
FILE* in; int s[2][5];
in=fopen("input","r+");
read(in,s);
s[1][0]=7;
write(in,s);
}

void read(FILE* in, int s[][5]) {
    int i, j, x;
    for (i = 0; i<2; ++i) {
         for (j = 0; j<5; ++j) {
            fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &x);
            s[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
}
void write(FILE* out;int s[][5]){
int i, j, x;
    for (i = 0; i<2; ++i) {
         for (j = 0; j<5; ++j) {
            fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &x);
            s[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Open the file `r`, then close after `read()` and reopen before `write` with `w`. That way, you just overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

between read and write function use:

```
fclose(in);
in = fopen("input","r")
```